# What does OP stand for?

Tags: support

I keep seeing the term OP in reference to someone who has asked a question and I wanted to know what words OP stand for.

Comment: original poster

Comment: Thanks can you make that an answer so I csn

Comment: I'm only 97% sure about that. Probably someone else will swoop in with references and charts and a brilliant history of the term, and you can accept that answer.

Comment: @amarillo : I swooped in, but not with a history and references and charts.  I didn't see your comment.  Obie sent me here, and I went straight for the answer.

Comment: @Praxis I’ll count your link to his profile as qualifying for "brilliant." You can add the charts and stuff later. Google n-grams, a bibliography... you know. Or you could leave the answer how it is. Either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Original poster

For instance, on the question above, [**you**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57258/the-mandolorian) are the OP.